# How to create a list of list of numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to create a function that makes a board of size row and column and then populate that with zeros. 
mkBoard 2 3 would make
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

I don't really know where to start as I am new to Haskell programming I was thinking that the function would be something like this:

```
mkBoard m n= [m | ???? take n (repeat 0)]
```

But I am not sure if this would be the correct approach.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `take n (repeat 0)` is called `replicate`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate

Comment: Hint: you can simply apply the `replicate` function (mentioned by @arrowd) twice with the appropriate arguments, to get what you want.

Comment: If you feel totally stuck in a problem like this you're better served by 1) breaking it into subproblems, and then 2) solving them with explicit recursion, before moving on. Try writing replicate yourself.

Answer (score 4):

As @arrowd already mentioned, there is a `replicate` function for `take n (repeat x)`. You can create one row of your board with `replicate n 0`, and then create a board of such rows like `mkBoard m n = replicate m (replicate n 0)`.

Also you can create more generic version of this function to fill the field with any value:

```
genericMkBoard :: a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]]
genericMkBoard x m n = replicate m (replicate n x)
```

And define your `mkBoard` with [partial application](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions):

```
mkBoard = genericMkBoard 0
```

**UPD**: Also you can make it like this to be more consistent with `replicate` (thanks to @chepner):

```
replicate2D m n x = replicate m (replicate n x)

mkBoard m n = replicate2D m n 0
```

Comment: I might make the type `Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]]` to be consistent with `replicate`. Then `genericMkBoard m n = replicate m . replicate n`.

Comment: @chepner I thought about it, but I used a principle "arguments that are likely to be defaulted should go first, so you can default them with currying"

Comment: @chepner I think it depends on your usage: if your common usage is `mkBoard :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]`, then my version is handier, but if you need something like `boardOf :: a -> [[a]]` with already captured size, then your way is more appropriate, like `boardOf = genericMkBoard defaultH defaultW`

Comment: Yeah, I was originally going to comment that it would be more likely that you would specify a size, *then* decide what to fill the board with, but I couldn't convince myself that was true.

Comment: Or you could define some monstrosity like `genericMkBoard = flip ((.) . replicate) . flip replicate` :)

Comment: @chepner Yeah, point-free notation is sometimes not the most readable thing :) I often try to rewrite my code with point-free style, but get something scary, so I have to go back for simple one

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use list comprehension here. We can make use of [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) that will convert an `Int` *n* and an `a` to a list that repeats that value *n* times.

We thus can construct a list of three `0`s with `replicate 3 0`. We can then use `replicate` a second time to construct a list that contains that list two times for example.

```
mkBoard :: Num n => Int -> Int -> [[n]]
mkBoard m n = replicate m (replicate n 0)
```